# How to find a basis for a vector space

Tags: linear-algebra

I would like to ask for your guidance in regards with the following:

> Let $V$ be the vector space that includes all the polynomials whose degree is $\le 3$, with real number as coefficients. Prove that $W=\{f\in V: f(2)=0\}$ is subspace of $V$ and find a basis of $W$.

It is familiar to me how to prove that a space is or not a subspace of a specific vector space and how to find a basis using Gauss Elimination, but how to do these steps without having the exact constraints of $V$?

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Maths SX!

You have to use some arithmetic of polynomials. Here's a hint/sketch:

For any polynomial $f$, $\alpha$ is a root of $f$ if and only  if $f$ is divisible  by $X-\alpha$.

So here, $W$ made up of polynomials $f$ of degree $\le 3$ for which  there exists a polynomial $g$ such that 
$$f(X)=(X-2)g(X).$$
*Question*: What is $\deg g$? Can you show the set of such $g$s is also a subspace of $V$, find a basis for them and deduce a basis for $W$?

Answer (score 0):

Take arbitrarily $p(x)=a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+a_3x^3 \in V$.

Now  $$p(x) \in W \implies p(2)=0  \implies a_0+2a_1+4a_2+8a_3=0$$
Thus $a_0=-(2a_1+4a_2+8a_3)$ and hence $p$ can be written as $$p(x)=-(2a_1+4a_2+8a_3)+a_1x+a_2x^2+a_3x^3\\=a_1 \color{red}{(x-2)}+a_2 \color{red}{(x^2-4)}+a_3\color{red}{(x^3-8)}$$

Hence...?